# Could someone give me some adviceabout WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I am making a user control that is databound. The query results include a collection of objects (A) where A has a collction of other results (B). So A contains multilple B.

in the user control I want to represent the collection A as expanders and B as buttons inside of the expanders. This is what I got

```
<UserControl x:Class="GuideLib.ModuleControls.uclQuestions"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<ItemsControl x:Name="ictlAnswers" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="Gray">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander ExpandDirection="Down" Background="DarkGray">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="White"/>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ListBox x:Name="SubListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Question}" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="10,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Tag="{Binding Path=ID}">
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have multiple problems.

1: I can not get the buttons in the expanders to strech horizontally

2: How can I set the Tag property of the button to be the whole object of B

3: Why does the default mouseover effect still execute.

Thanks

Comment: Please update the title of the question to something more useful. If that is hard you are probably asking too many questions in one topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here goes:

**1.** You need to set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on the `ListBox` and on the `StackPanel` inside `DataTemplate` set `Orientation="Vertical"`

**2.** set `Tag="{Binding .}"` on the `Button`

**3.** Update your `Button.Style` to something like:

```
<Button.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <ContentPresenter />
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Orange" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

finally before you add Question **4.** remember `ListBoxItem` has a `Style` of it's own. So to completely override the effect on `MouseOver` when not on the `Button` but in the "Item" you have to provide a custom `Style` for `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`

Oh and **Start Using** [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It helps you debug Layout issues. Think you would have been able to solve problem 1 with it cos it would have shown you that your `ContentPresenter` of `ListBoxItem` was using required Width and not Stretching.

Comment: I found the answer in the meantime but could not remove the button boder. It looks like your solution solves this problem as well
Still learning wpf.

Thanks man. you've been of a lot of assistence

Comment: Another thing, ... how do I add a padding to the button so there is a bigger space between the text and button.

Comment: Found it. add  the value to the contentpresenter's margin propery

Comment: @user853710 Please create a new question if your needing help with anything else than add to the same thread. Try to keep your questions just about 1 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just from taking a quick look at it.. for question 2 try doing this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="10,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Tag="{Binding}">
```

That should make it bind to the items in the ListBox.